# How to select the first mail from Outbox of Outlook Addin in C# Visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a Outlook Add-In from which I want to access Outbox of mail item and get the first mail of outbox programmatically in C# Visual Studio.

Comment: First in what sense? The oldest? The newest? Why do you want to do anything with the messages in the Outbox folder? Doing that will cancel the message submission.

Comment: I ideally have to select the "Newest" mail from outbox folder Once it is selected it has to perform the click action on button  click on the which is there on top inside the Tab. Can yuh Assest me how to do this?

Comment: I have to do all this programmatically

Comment: Why? The message is in the Outbox folder and it about to be sent out and moved to the Sent Items folder. Why do you want to do anything with that message?

Comment: I have an application where i want to Insert the Outbox mail into that store...Not that i want to do the cut paste operation .Let the document remain in outbox but should also go in to the store where i want to store it.

Comment: This process can be done with the click of button on the tab.But before that i want to select the recent "Newest" mail from Outbox.

Comment: Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.
                   GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox Outlook.Items items = inbox.Items; Items gives all the mails from outlook but i want first Newest mail to be selected automatically

Comment: A message is moved to the Outbox folder automatically when you call MailItem.Send. Why would you want to create a message there? And why does it need to ne selected? Do you expect the user to do anything with it?

Comment: I want to move from Outbox to another Store Like Some Database. In that case i want only the newest mail to be selected automatically and perform the click action on button

Comment: What button? If you want to move a message programmatically, just call MailItem.Move. But the messages in the Outbox folder are being submitted, touching a message there in any way will abort the submission process. I doubt your users will appreciate that.

Comment: Its not move operation on select of mail i have to perform context menu item click on a custom item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924.aspx) method of the Store class. This method is similar to the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx) method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

```
Sub ChangeCurrentFolder() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = _ 
 myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)  
End Sub
```

Use the [GetFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff861538.aspx) method of the Items class to get the first object in the collection. Returns Nothing if no first object exists, for example, if there are no objects in the collection. To ensure correct operation of the GetFirst, GetLast, GetNext, and GetPrevious methods in a large collection, call GetFirst before calling GetNext on that collection and call GetLast before calling GetPrevious. To ensure that you are always making the calls on the same collection, create an explicit variable that refers to that collection before entering the loop.

You may find the [How To: Get any standard / default folder in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/05/how-to-get-any-standard-default-folder-in-outlook/) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information .Can i get the same code in C#?

Comment: See [How To: Get any standard / default folder in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/05/how-to-get-any-standard-default-folder-in-outlook/) for the sample code in C#.